# Export multidimensional array in excel or csv in laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, collections, foreach, export-to-excel

Really it's complicated situation for me right now.

Here I have to export multidimensional array data into excel which is looks like below image, but I'm unable to make it possible.

Please help me to export the multidimensional array data to export in excel.

I have an array from relational query like:

```
$array = [
    0 => [
        'name' => 'Devat Karetha',
    ],
    1 => [
        'name' => 'John Doe',
        'schools' => [
            0 => [
                'school_name' => 'ABC School',
                'school_address' => 'ABC Address',
            ],
            1 => [
                'school_name' => 'XYZ School',
                'school_address' => 'XYZ Address',
            ]
        ],
        'sports' => [
            0 => [
                'id' => 8,
                'sport_type' => [
                    'id' => 2
                    'sport_type_name' => 'ABC Sport'
                ],
            ],
            1 => [
                'id' => 8,
                'sport_type' => [
                    'id' => 3
                    'sport_type_name' => 'ABC Sport'
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    2 => [
        'name' => 'Utkarsh Raval',
        'schools' => [],
        'sports' => [
            0 => [
                'id' => 8,
                'sport_type' => [
                    'id' => 2
                    'sport_type_name' => 'DEKTS Sport'
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'centre' => [
            0 => [
                'id' => 4,
                'centre_name' => 'ABC Centre',
                'centre_mobile' => '9898989898',
            ],
            1 => [
                'id' => 5,
                'centre_name' => 'XYZ Centre',
                'centre_mobile' => '7878787878',
            ],
        ]
    ],
];
```

[image: Demo excel will looks like this image]

Thank You...:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I putting my own answer of this question - may be it'll help someone to understand the export functionality with multidimensional array:

```
    $newArr = [];
    $arr = [];
    foreach($result as $key => $value) {
        $count = [count($value['schools']),count($value['centre']),count($value['sports'])];
        $arrMax = max($count);
        if($arrMax > 0){
            for($i=0; $i < $arrMax; $i++){
                $arrIndex = $i;
                $arr['sr_no'] = '';
                $arr['name'] = '';
                if($arrIndex == '0'){
                    $arr['sr_no'] = $key + 1;
                    $arr['name'] = isset($value['name']) ? $value['name'] : '';
                }
                $arr['school_name'] = isset($value['schools'][$arrIndex]['school_name']) ? $value['schools'][$arrIndex]['school_name'] : '';
                $arr['school_address'] = isset($value['schools'][$arrIndex]['school_address']) ? $value['schools'][$arrIndex]['school_address'] : '';
                $arr['sport_type_name'] = isset($value['sports'][$arrIndex]['sport_type']['sport_type_name']) ? $value['sports'][$arrIndex]['sport_type']['sport_type_name'] : '';
                $arr['centre_name'] = isset($value['centre'][$arrIndex]['centre_name']) ? $value['centre'][$arrIndex]['centre_name'] : '';
                $arr['centre_mobile'] = isset($value['centre'][$arrIndex]['centre_mobile']) ? $value['centre'][$arrIndex]['centre_mobile'] : '';
                $newArr[] = $arr;
            }
        } else {
            $arr['sr_no'] = $key + 1;
            $arr['name'] = isset($value['name']) ? $value['name'] : '';
            $arr['school_name'] = '';
            $arr['school_address'] = '';
            $arr['sport_type_name'] = '';
            $arr['centre_name'] = '';
            $arr['centre_mobile'] = '';
            $newArr[] = $arr;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $excel
     */
    \Excel::create('advance-report-'.date('d-m-YTH-i-s'), function($excel) use($newArr) {

        $excel->sheet('Sheet 1', function($sheet) use($newArr) {

            $sheet->fromArray($newArr);
            // Freeze first row
            $sheet->freezeFirstRow();
            // Set height for header
            $sheet->setHeight(1, 30);
            // Modify properties of header
            $sheet->cells('A1:AS1', function($cells) {
                $cells->setBackground('#345fbc');
                $cells->setFontColor('#ffffff');
                $cells->setValignment('center');
            });

            for( $intRowNumber = 1; $intRowNumber <= count($newArr) + 1; $intRowNumber++){
                laravelExcel($sheet, $intRowNumber); //helper function
            }

        });

    })->export('xls');
```

In Helper File:

```
/**
 * @param null $sheet
 * @param null $intRowNumber
 */
function laravelExcel($sheet = null, $intRowNumber = null)
{
    try {
        $sheet->setSize('A' . $intRowNumber, 10, 18);
        $sheet->setSize('B' . $intRowNumber, 20, 18);
        $sheet->setSize('C' . $intRowNumber, 20, 18);
        $sheet->setSize('D' . $intRowNumber, 20, 18);
        $sheet->setSize('E' . $intRowNumber, 35, 18);
        $sheet->setSize('F' . $intRowNumber, 15, 18);
        $sheet->setSize('G' . $intRowNumber, 15, 18);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where these structures are used inside the laravel export ? re-edit and add the method name to use in latest versions