# Converting Multi Index Excel file to array in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I have used maatwebsite/excel 2.1 to read the excel file but i faced problem while reading multiple heading excel file(EX: as shown in first fig). I can't read all the data as it skipped all the rows except first of second heading(As shown in second fig highlighted).

[First Image with excel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAtTZ.png)

[Second Image with only fetched data highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCglg.jpg)

The data was fetched as:

```
[
    {"name":"First","0":"F","address":"Country","result":"A"}, 
    {"name":"foo","0":456,"address":"nep","result":324}, 
    {"name":"bar","0":456,"address":"aus","result":324}, 
    {"name":"baz","0":222,"address":"uk","result":21}
    ]
```

Skipping all the other row of data. So, i want ask for help in fetching all data and also in organised way if possible EX:

```
["name":{
            "first":"foo",
            "middle":" ",
            "last":"asd"
           },
  "address":{
             "country":"nep",
               ...
               ],
 ...
]
```

OR AS

```
[{
   "name.first":"foo",
   "name.middle":" ",
   "name.last":"asd",
   "address.country":"nep",
    ......}]
```

If this is not possible with available library than can anyone tell me how the excel individual cell data is read in PHP(core level).

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Comment: Recently I have did something you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50790846/export-multidimensional-array-in-excel-or-csv-in-laravel

Comment: @dekts You have asked on question about exporting data to excel but i have problem in importing it . But thanks for your reply